# How to convert a string to binary format in Python

Tags: python, string, binary, type-conversion

I have to convert a string of numbers to a binary format. The sequence goes from 1 to 10. If the string contains a '1', then a 1 must be returned in the first position. If the string contains a '4', then a 1 must be returned in the 4th position. If the number is missing, then a 0 is returned in its position. So an empty string would return 00000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
valid_digits = '12345678'
number = '125'
binary = ''.join(['1' if i in number else '0' for i in valid_digits])
```

Output:

```
'11001000'
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much. It works!!! I had never seen .join before.

Comment: Python has very useful `string` operations. I would suggest you to check them out, you will most certainly find them very useful.